# Maven best practice - compile, deploy and test

Tags: maven, testing, deployment, compilation

Is it possible with Maven to compile, package, deploy into AS and run the tests against the AS? Until now all these steps were done by Ant.

SK

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Use the Failsafe plugin as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html).